# How do I use OpenSearch Serverless with AWS Amplify (Graphql and AppSync)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, graphql, aws-amplify, opensearch

I'm developing an app in NextJS with Amplify and need to use OpenSearch Serverless with my data. Since I'm using Amplify, my data uses Appsync, Dynamodb and Graphql under the hood.

I've tried adding the `@searchable` directive to one of my models in my graphql schema, however that creates an OpenSearch domain which uses a **managed cluster**. I want to use the new OpenSearch **Serverless** INSTEAD of the managed cluster.